# Could not find method from the newer API with using TargetApi annotation

Tags: android, eclipse

Iwant to use the next code for applying SharedPreferences for all Android APIs since 4.

```
/**
 * The apply method was introduced 
 * in Android API level 9.<br> Calling it causes a safe asynchronous write 
 * of the SharedPreferences.Editor object to be performed. Because
 * it is asynchronous, it is the preferred technique for saving SharedPreferences.<br> 
 * So we should use appropriate method if we doesn`t need confirmation of success.
 * In this case we should use old commit method.
 */
@TargetApi(9)
    public static void applySharedPreferences(SharedPreferences.Editor editor){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9){
        editor.commit();
    } else {
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Project target API is 10 (set in Project Properties).
It works fine on API 8, but when I try to run it on API 4 it is crashed with the next message:

```
11-18 20:21:45.782: E/dalvikvm(323): Could not find method android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.apply, referenced from method my.package.utils.Utils.applySharedPreferences
```

It normally installs on the device but crashing during the starting. Why is it happens when this method (apply) isn`t ever used in this API ?

Thanks

Comment: This method isn`t ever call before crashing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It works fine on API 8, but when I try to run it on API 4 it is crashed with the next message:

Dalvik, in Android 1.x, was very conservative, and would crash if you try to load a class that contains a reference that it cannot resolve -- in this case, `apply()`. Your choices are:

1. Drop support for Android 1.x, or
2. Do not use `apply()`, but just always use `commit()` in your own background thread, or
3. Create another class (e.g., `GingerbreadHelper`) with a static `apply()` method that takes your `SharedPreferences.Editor` as a parameter and calls `apply()` on it. Then, change your `applySharedPreferences()` to use `GingerbreadHelper.apply(editor)` instead of `editor.apply()`. So long as you never load `GingerbreadHelper` on the Android 1.x device, you will avoid the `VerifyError`.

Comment: Ahh so this is a Dalvik error! Glad I don't target API 4 devices anymore, I'm hoping this dalvik bug has been fixed API7+?

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins: Android 2.0 ushered in a kinder, gentler Dalvik that will not immediately fail when loading the class. It will wait until  you try to *use* the reference that it could not resolve, then crash. That helps tremendously in this `Build`-based version guard blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Isnt that the wrong way round?

Shouldn't that be:

```
@TargetApi(9)
public static void applySharedPreferences(SharedPreferences.Editor editor)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    {
        editor.apply();
    }
    else
    {
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

That will fix if for ya!

Although even better!

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public static void applySharedPreferences(final SharedPreferences.Editor editor)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    {
        editor.apply();
    }
    else
    {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                editor.commit();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Its now always async!

Comment: Well thats depressing, I've used the above in some large apps and never had it crash. Little bit concerning you are having an issue, what device?

Comment: Although my code is valid see @commonsguy response, seems this is a Dalvik bug pre 2.x devices.